# Google App Engine Deploy Error When Deploying Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently I am trying to deploy a server for Mit App Inventor, when I browser the project it looks just fine and the local host works as well. The problem is that when I try to deploy it I get an error. I am using python 2.7.8. By the way I am doing this project from my other gmail account. 
I have tried and retried a thousand times, but with no result. Can you please help me?
[This is the main error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzPgo.png)

[It says that that's an error when reading a line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3moV9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all relevant information, especially error messages, directly into the question instead of linking to screenshots. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste the text into your post and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you're still using the Google App Engine Launcher which I think was deprecated and is no longer supported. The point is that it still uses appcfg.py to deploy and from the error message you get it also tries to use login/password for authentication which is also no longer supported.

Today you should use the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download) and the gcloud command line to manage/deploy your app. I'm confident that will solve your issue.